# Don't get right uploaded file name in IE8 (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC project I have a form to upload a file. If I use Google Chrome, Firefox or Opera to upload a file, I get only the file name like `Inventory_June_2013.xlsx`.

When I use IE8 to upload a file, I get a file name like 
`C:\Documents and Settings\gornel\My Documents\Inventory_June_2013.xlsx`.

How to fix this?

**UPD**
This is my **File.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace Argussite.SupplierService.Core.Domain
{
public class File : Entity
{
    public const int ContentTypeLength = 100;
    public const int FileNameLength = 100;
    public const int StorageNameLength = 100;

    protected File()
    {}

    public File(string name, string contentType, long fileSize)
    {
        Name = name;
        ContentType = contentType;
        FileSize = fileSize;
        StorageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
        UploadTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Required, MaxLength(FileNameLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(ContentTypeLength)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public long FileSize { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(StorageNameLength)]
    public string StorageName { get; set; }

    public DateTime UploadTime { get; set; }
}
}
```

And it's code from controller

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(Guid eventId, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //...
        var document = new File(file.FileName, file.ContentType, file.ContentLength);
        @event.FileId = document.Id;
        @event.ActualDate = document.UploadTime;

        Context.Files.Add(document);

        file.SaveAs(GetFilePath(document.StorageName));

        Register(new DocumentUploadedNotification(@event, @event.DocumentType, document, UrlBuilder));

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Suppliers", new { id = @event.SupplierId });
    }
```

I use class HttpPostedFileBase and property FileName.

Comment: Can you show the code where you process the uploaded file?

Comment: So which variable in all of this code is carrying the wrong value?

Comment: Please remove unnecessary code, which is not valuable for the question.

Comment: Now it's a bit clearer, and in that case your question is answered in [HttpPostedFile.FileName - Different from IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382464/httppostedfile-filename-different-from-ie).

Answer (score 2):

It's known that IE returns full path while other browsers supply only file name. Unfortunately, it's the case which you have to handle by yourself, asp.net cannot help with it.

You may take only file name part using [Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method.

Comment: I use this code `var document = new File(file.FileName, file.ContentType, file.ContentLength);` How should I change it?

Comment: Please update your question with this code. And show what `file` is